# Trying to Locate Aruco Fiducials with USB camera Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, opencv, fiducial-markers

I have some code I think should be working using open CV to detect a set of fiducials. For some reason, I cant get my code to run. It gives the error "Unable to stop the stream: Invalid argument"

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat markerImage;
    VideoCapture cap;

    // open the default camera, use something different from 0 otherwise;
    // Check VideoCapture documentation.
    if(!cap.open(1))
        return 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        if( frame.empty() ) break; // end of video stream


        std::vector<int> markerIds;
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> markerCorners, rejectedCandidates;
        cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::DetectorParameters> parameters = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters::create();
        cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_5X5_50);
        cv::aruco::detectMarkers(frame, dictionary, markerCorners, markerIds, parameters, rejectedCandidates);
        cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(frame, markerCorners, markerIds);

        imshow("Camera)", frame);   


        if( waitKey(10) == 27 ) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC 
    }
    // the camera will be closed automatically upon exit
    // cap.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: complete error output please. that can't be all.

Comment: that is the entire error message... I compile using >>cmake . then >>make and then enter in ./Aruco into the command line and all I get out is "Unable to stop the stream: Invalid Argument"

Comment: can you view that webcam with any other programs? which? what exact brand and model is it?